# How to consume a WCF service with Jscript.NET but not using any html? Lawson Smart Office Script

Tags: wcf, jscript.net

How do you consume a wcf service with jscript.net but not using any html?  My wcf service is working fine and I am using it with other programs but I don't know how to reference it with soley jscript.net code. I am trying to write a script for a Lawson Smart Office Panel and it uses jscript.net (why use jscript.net? it's coded in c#.  real dumb) so I need to call my wcf service but don't know how.  My wcf service uses a net/tcp endpoint and its running on a virtual machine on the same network.  I tried using DashboardTaskService.Manager.LaunchTask(uri) but I don't think that's the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

http://smartofficeblog.com/2013/06/20/script-assemblies-in-mforms/
If you work like this you get to write C# code and use it as a Jscript in M3, I would never go back to just writing Jscript.